# Arraylist addAll() method throwing exception

Tags: java, arrays, list, collections, arraylist

Why I am getting exception while executing the following code.

```
  String[] array1 = {"A","B","C","D","E"};
  String[] array2 = {"F","G","H","I"}; 
  List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array1);
  list.addAll(Arrays.asList(array2)); //here getting exception
```

Exception

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(Unknown Source)
at Sample6.main(Sample6.java:19)
```

But this code working well.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.as.asList(array1));        
list.addAll(Arrays.asList(array2));
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you read the javadoc of Arrays.asList()?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**First case**

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array1);
list.addAll(Arrays.asList(array2));
```

Since `list`  in the first case is `Unmodifiable`(in terms of size) because it is returned by `asList` method.

From docs of [asList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.

So when you are directly referring to that, you endup with `exception` when you try to modify it.

**Second case**

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.as.asList(array1));
```

Here you are not referring to the `list` directly. You are creating a new `ArrayList` and using the data of the list returned by `Arrays.as.asList(array1)` ,which is not a `Unmodifiable`(in terms of size).

Comment: Actually, the `List` returned by `Arrays.asList` is modifiable: you can call the `.set()` method on it. It is just fixed sized.

Comment: @EtienneMiret I mean adding `new` elements,since OP using addAll method. Updated :).

Comment: +1 thanks suresh. Now understood Arrays.asList will return Unmodifiable list.

Comment: @Prabhakaran Glad it help. Remember Unmodifiable in terms of size :). You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.asList()`

This always returns an unmodifiable list.